# App crashing after adding final modifier to Edit Text

Tags: android, events, android-edittext

I have an edit text i need to hook to textchanged event to to do a task.I had defined the overrdiimg for edittext first but after adding the text extraction code in the text chnaged event the IDE Flagged an error and auto corrected it by adding a `final` modifier in the line
like this

```
 final EditText et1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
```

After chnaging the text the app crahses so i tried to retrive the edittext 2 times first for hooking to the event then for fetching the text,then also the app crashes.
The IDE had prompted me to add the final modifier in similar cases before but it had crashed the app so i had added the fetchbyID at the point where the object was needed

```
 EditText et1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        et1.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

              @Override
              public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

                 new Thread(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                        ImageView img=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
                      EditText et=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
                        img.setImageBitmap(thumbnail);
                          Bitmap b = workwithtext(thumbnail,et.getText().toString(),10);
                          img.setImageBitmap(b);
                        }
                      }).start();
              }

              @Override
              public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

              }

              @Override
              public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

              }
            });
```

Please help me solve this issue

Answer (score 1):

It crashes because you are trying to modify a UI component from a non UI thread.

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
             public void run() {
                 ImageView img=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
                 //...                       
                 img.setImageBitmap(thumbnail);
                 //...
                 }
}).start();
```

Comment: okay,how can i set the imageview,since the process may freeze the UI?

Comment: You could use an `AsyncTask`, but I don't understand why this should be done in `onTextChanged()`. This means every time a character is typed, the images are set. Is this really what you want?

Comment: how ? can you give an exmaple

Comment: Yeah every time a character is typed it should be changed,will that be a problem?

Comment: @AndyRes also everytime `onTextChanged(`) is called op is starting a thread. i agree on your second comment

Answer (score 0):

Have the EditText et1 as a field in your class rather than a local variable.

Comment: could you explain a bit,im new to android just starting

Comment: have et1 has a field, i.e. private EditText et1; Then in your method (probably onCreate) use: et1 = findViewByID();

Answer (score 0):

You are updating ui from a background therad which is not possible. Also move your view intialization to `onCreate`.

```
  img.setImageBitmap(b); // updating ui from thread not possible
```

Use `runOnUiThread` to update ui

```
     runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
     public void run() {
           // update ui here
     }
     });
```

Note you are starting a new thread everytime your `onTextChanged` is called which is not good. Also you initialize imageview and editext everytime in the threads run method which is not required.

Comment: Thanks,but will this freeze the UI?Say if i put the img.setImageBitmap(b); after the thread code,will the image be set after thread is finished or will it be set in the normal code flow?

Comment: @techno read this. http://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-anr.html. If your blocking ui thread yes. but as Andy Res commented do you really need this

Comment: @techno do you really need a thread fro what your doing? are you doing any network realted stuff in `workwithtext`.

Comment: Well i dont know,iam a newbie to android there is no network activity just drawing on bitmap,i had used Background worker for similar things on c# Is a new thread needed,if the image has to updated continuously as the text is changed

Comment: @techno  `workwithtext` does long running operation? i don't think you need a thread for what your doing.